# Difference between java.awt.* and java.awt.event.*

Tags: java

What is difference between `java.awt.*` and `java.awt.event.*`?

Comment: Difference in what sense? One is a subpackage of another but I doubt that's what you're asking.

Comment: The difference is `.event`... Have you read that packages javadocs?

Answer (score 5):

It's just two different packages.

When you say `import java.awt.*` it imports only those classes which belong exactly to `java.awt` package, not to its subpackages.

That's why when you want to use events you have also import `java.awt.event`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean while importing? They are different packages. They aren't necessarily related. Importing java.awt.* doesn't import java.awt.event.*